# MYSQL:Selecting SUM of a column but the column is based of another row ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have the sum of the beginning inventory of the entire year. The beginning inventory is based of the end_inventory of another month. The beginning_inventory_id contains the ID of another row which points to the end_inventory. How do I properly get the sum of the beginning_inventory of a certain year when it's based of another row's end_inventory. I have the following table

| id | time_period | beginning_inventory_id | end_inventory | gross_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 | null | 1000 | 500 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | 1 | 2000 | 500 |
| 3 | 2020-11-01 | 2 | 3000 | 500 |
| 4 | 2020-12-01 | 3 | 4000 | 500 |
| 5 | 2021-01-01 | 4 | 5000 | 500 |

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT SUM(a.gross_sales) as gross_sales, SUM(a.end_inventory) as end_inventory,
                    
(SELECT SUM(b.end_inventory) FROM fs_summary as b WHERE a.beginning_inventory_id = b.id) as beginning_inventory
                    
FROM fs_summary as a
                    
WHERE YEAR(a.time_period) = 2020
```

Output I would like to generate is:

1. beginning_inventory = 6000
2. end_inventory = 10000
3. gross_sales = 2000

Instead, I am getting null on the beginning_inventory.

Any help would be great!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is this `beginning_inventory = 6000` stored in your database? Or is it on a sticky note on your terminal...

Comment: Beginning_inventory is not stored. I need to generate the end inventory of the id in the beginning_inventory_id - the year 2020 should generate 6000

Comment: @Strawberry Is there something wrong with my question? The sql query works, I indicated the expected and ideal outputs. As well as detailed my table as well as the data in it too

Comment: I can only refer you again to my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Assuming that you want to retrieve data from 1 table with self join.

```
SELECT SUM(a.gross_sales),SUM(a.end_inventory),SUM(b.end_inventory)
FROM fs_summary a, fs_aummary b
WHERE b.id=a.beginning_inventory_id AND YEAR(a.time_period) = 2020
```

using self join can help you in this situation

**EDIT:** You can also write this script as,

```
SELECT SUM(a.gross_sales),SUM(a.end_inventory),SUM(b.end_inventory)
FROM fs_summary a
INNER JOIN fs_aummary b
ON b.id=a.beginning_inventory_id 
WHERE YEAR(a.time_period) = 2020
```

Comment: sorry that was written by mistake. this query should work. it is for 1 table

Comment: How do solutions with commas in the `FROM` clause get upvotes?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You mean one cannot use comma in FROM Clause?

Comment: @BilalBinZia . . . One _should not_.  Proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax has been part of SQL for decades.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there is no difference performance wise. But yes `JOIN` makes the query more readable

Answer (score 1):

Using self-join SQL you can achieve your result instead of sub-queries.

You should specify the same table with two different names. Your query looks as below

```
select sum(virtual_tb.end_inventory) as 'beginning_inventory', sum(org_tb.end_inventory) as 'end_inventory', sum(org_tb.gross_sales)  as 'gross_sales'
from fs_summary org_tb left join fs_aummary virtual_tb on (virtual_tb.beginning_inventory_id = org_tb.id) 
where year(org_tb.time_period) = 2020;
```

---

(Approx Output)

| beginning_inventory | end_inventory | gross_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6000 | 10000 | 2000 |